# Not able to get google map api response to parse

Tags: ios, swift, api

I have used the google api to fetch nearby locations. I have made the api call and have got the proper results(json response)also.

This is the model class I have made for parsing the json response

```
class Locations: Codable {

  var locationName: String?
  var locationAddress: String?

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case locationName = "name"
    case locationAddress = "vicinity"

  }

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    locationName = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .locationName)
    locationAddress = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .locationAddress)

  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(locationName, forKey: .locationName)
    try container.encode(locationAddress, forKey: .locationAddress)

  }
}
```

In the above class, I have mentioned only two variables namely location and address since I want to display just those two values on my tableview.

But after fetching the results, in this part below, I’m not able to go inside the if let condition

```
WebServiceClient.shared.getNearbyLocationsList(withParameters: parameters, lattitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude) { [weak self] (isSuccess, result) in
      guard let `self` = self else { return }
      if isSuccess, result != nil {
        print("Successfully fetched nearby locations!")

//I have data in the result but it is not going into the if-let condition.
        if let productService = result?["results"] as? [[String: Any]] ,
          let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: productService as Any, options: []),
          let locationsList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Locations].self, from: jsonData) {
          self.locationsList = locationsList          

        }
```

This is a small snippet of the api response...

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CsQEQAIAAG….”,
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.07456,
               "lng" : 74.86545
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.2456,
                  "lng" : 74.98456
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.8564,
                  "lng" : 76.7745645
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : “sdf.png",
         "id" : "2e66c82c2e8d7149bd7e026089ff5dedb8346bd5",
         "name" : "Mumbai",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2304,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111225135501811810933/photos\"\u003eRamkrishna Pudasaini\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRZAAAA4WHsIxpFh…”,
               "width" : 3456
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "Chbdfbdfb_tpF0",
         "reference" : "ChIJbnfgh54_tpF0",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ],
         "vicinity" : "Mumbai"
      }
],
“status” : “OK”
}
```

And from this api response, I wanted to get the data associated with name and vicinity.

Comment: What is `result`? `Data`, `String`, `Dictionary` or what?

Comment: `result` is a `Dictionary` @vadian. It's given as `let result: [String : Any]?`

Comment: Then put the two *throwing* methods in a `do - catch` block and check the error. By the way to get only those two values the double encoding and decoding is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: But in case a need arises in the future, @vadian, I could add more variables to the model class and have the additional data..:) Also since I haven't much used encoder-decoder, it would have been good if i knew what is going wrong currently...Could you maybe mind suggesting an answer...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please shift JSONDecoder part in the do-catch statement and it will work.

```
if let productService = result?["results"] as? [[String: Any]] ,
          let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: productService as Any, options: []) {

     do {

         let locationsList = try JSONDecoder().decode([LocationInfo].self, from: jsonData)
         self.locationsList = locationsList          

      } catch {

         print("error \(error)"

      }

 }
```

Comment: Never print `localizedDescription` in a `JSONDecoder` catch block. You will get a meaningless generic error message. Print the `error` instance

Comment: Thanks a lot @Muhammad Waqas Bhati. It has worked..:)

Comment: So what do you suggest @vadian..?

Comment: Also @Muhammad Waqas Bhati...would you mind suggesting what was it that I was doing wrong..?